# my phone is charging while connected to the laptop but not recognized

Tags: samsung

i was trying to connect my samsung galaxy tab 2 7.0 to my laptop but is not recognized. it was charging and i tried to look at the internet for the solution but nothing worked out. i tried debugging it and hitting the build number on my tab. i tried everything but nothing happened. i only have one laptop and one connector.
   i was trying to recover my deleted photos so im asking for your help. i'll appreciate everything you did.

Comment: It's a common problem. Either your cable is damaged or ports of your laptop are damaged. You can also see an Unkown device in USB Controllers category of Device Manager in your laptop (shortcut- Win+x - >m). Try changing the cable first

Comment: Do you have at least Samsung drivers installed?

Comment: If you actually "tried everything" then there's no way we can help you. But if you [edit] your question to say what you tried, maybe someone can suggest something you haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows try to open **Device Manager** then you may see it under "other devices" as MTP device for example

[image]

so double-click on it ==> Driver tab ==> update driver ==> you will see
[image]

try both, but in second option let your computer search in this location (**C:\Windows\WinSXS**)by typing it in the shown text field.
I hope this help you

Answer (score -1):

Or you can simply download your samsung Usb setup from internet and simply install it in your computer. It seems like you have no software to handle your android device when connected to pc.